# JQuery Tab - Make Selected tab clickable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I basically need the current selected tab to remain clickable (meaning
the link should still be active).

The content in the tab is loaded through ajax and can change, so the
way the person can "refresh" the content it by clicking the tab again.
But the default settings make the tab not clickable once it's
selected, which makes the user have to click on another tab then back
to refresh the content.

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: That's not a good UI paradigm. Think of it this way, a user who comes to your page has to know that they must click the tab again to refresh. 

Instead, why not add a refresh icon or some message like what gmail or facebook do. 

Changing interface paradigms is generally not a good idea. :-)

Comment: I agree with AboutDev. You can easily add a Jquery UI refresh icon into the tab which will remain clickable in a selected tab, too.

Comment: I agree with the "Refresh" icon.. however, I am not sure how to fit it in with "JQuery UI" tabs.. If I add an image and an anchor link, it slips through the tab...

I have something like this:

        <div id="container">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/public/tab/policy"><span>Countries</span></a><a href="refresh();"><img src="refresh.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="/public/tab/urlcategories"><span>States</span></a><a href="refresh();"><img src="refresh.png"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

The tabs plugin will fire a 'tabsselect' Event when a tab is clicked.  Register a callback, whose second parameter will have a 'tab' property where you can check which tab you're on:

```
jQuery('#tabs-container').bind('tabsselect', function(e, tabsContainer) {

   jQuery(tabsContainer.tab).attr('href'));
});
```

EDITIED:

It will only fire when the tab actually changes.  Maybe bind on the anchor element within the tabs structure, and check for the ui-tabs-selected class.  There's decent documentation on the tabs plugin:  http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs .

Roughly:

```
jQuery('#tabs-container a').bind('click', function() {
    if(jQuery(e.target).hasClass('ui-tabs-selected')) {
        // do some stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Define onclick event of anchor to tab to reload or send to the parent page, like this

```
<div id="divTab">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tab_1">First Tab</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab_2" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="window.location.reload();">Second Tab</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab_3" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="window.location.replace('url');">Third Tab</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```